# Active Admin and dynamic and custom sortable column with attr_accesor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to add a custom sortable column in my **index do** of the activeadmin of the class A. For this I try several things?

1.-I trying to add a method to my model A.

```
  def foo
    if status == 'open'
    0
  elsif status == 'closed'
    1
  else
    2
 end
```

Then in my **index do** I wrote

```
 index do 
    column :foo, :sortable :foo
```

But I get the error foo does not a column of the model A.

2.- Another attemp is add a the attr_accesor key word to the model A and then in the **controller do** set the values of each row of my index table, but again without success. That is

```
class A 
   attr_accesor :foo

ActiveAdmin.register A
   controller do
      def index
         dataRecords = MyData.where("1=1")
         dataRecords.each do |data|
           data.foo = func()
         end
         @sortedData = dataRecords.sort_by{|data| data.foo}
      end
   end
```

Could you help me please?